# ¿Cuáles son sinónimos de "ni fu ni fa"?

Tags: modismos, sinónimos

Mis diccionarios me dan las siguientes variantes:

- así así
- regular
- sin pena ni gloria
- medianamente
- así no más
- tal cual (tal por cual)
- de por ahí
- de tres al cuatro
- como el tiempo malo
- que llueve o no llueve
- de tamaño regular

¿Qué variantes son más preferidas?
¿Hay otros sinónimos?
¿Existen variantes que no se puedan encontrar en el diccionario (palabrotas o jerga)?

---

He leído sus respuestas y parece que mis diccionarios me dan la traducción de "ni fu ni fa" incorrecta.

Es que he pensado que puedo usar esa frase, por ejemplo como la respuesta a la pregunta: ¿Qué tal? - Ni fu ni fa (en el sentido que la vida no es buena ni mala). O que estoy ni de buen ni de mal humor.

Ahora de sus respuestas sigue que no puedo usarla de esa manera. ¿Tengo razón?

Si tengo, entonces, pueden Uds. escribir algunas situaciones (ejemplos) que pueden precisar lo que esa frase significa y cuándo se puede usar?.
No está claro para mi la utilización de esa frase. No logro imaginarme que esa frase es algo que está cerca de "me da igual".

He encontrado dos variantes más:

- ni carne ni pescado    - exacto como en ruso;
- entre el sí y el no.

Comment: ¿cómo es textualmente en ruso *ni fu ni fa*? ¿Ни рыба, ни мясо? ¿O quizá либо рыба либо мясо?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Siguiendo el comentario de Diego Andrés Díaz Espinoza yo entiendo que podemos utilizar **ni fu ni fa** como un equivalente para frase rusa **ни рыба ни мясо**. Pero textualmente **ни рыба ни мясо** puedo traducir al español como **ni pezcado ni carne** y aquí Ud. puede ver que hay un equivalente que está muy cerca de **ни рыба ни мясо** - **ni carne ni pezcado** que ya está en mi lista.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Además teniendo en cuenta el comentario de Diego se puede traducir **ni fu ni fa** al ruso como **ни то ни сё** o **ни два ни полтора** (textualmente: ni 2 ni 1.5). Puedo equivocarme, pero no puedo recordar que he escuchado esas frases (rusas) en el sentido "me da igual" o "no me importa". Habitualmente significan que algo va no muy bien (o ni bien ni mal).

Comment: Pido perdón por unas faltas gramáticas en mis comentarios.

Comment: @JorgeCampos  Y además: **либо рыба, либо мясо** no es correcto en este contexto.  
Puedes utilizar esa frase como una respuesta a la pregunta: -¿Qué quieres para cenar: tenemos pescado, carne y mariscos? - Quiero или(либо) рыбу или(либо) мясо. No me gustan mariscos.

Comment: A simple vista no detecto errores gramaticales en tus comentarios; ergo, no veo razón para pedir perdón:). Con respecto a *«Puedo equivocarme, pero no puedo recordar que he escuchado esas frases (rusas) en el sentido "me da igual"»* yo recuerdo *мне фиолетово*. Pero esta expresión es diferente a *ni fu ni fa*. *Ni fu ni fa* expresa indefinición en una opinión, generalmente dando una respuesta. La frase rusa, en cambio, expresa indiferencia *мне фиолетово*.

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: [¿De dónde viene la expresión “ni fu ni fa”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15667/1674)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí te agrego algunos a tu lista.

En realidad esa frase `ni fu ni fa` solo se la he escuchado a personas mayores o en películas antiguas y se usa para expresar generalmente `Ni esto ni lo otro`:

- Me da lo mismo
- Ni más ni menos
- Me resbala
- Ni frío ni calor
- Por mi...
- Me da igual
- Me vale un ...< Palabrota que te venga a la mente >
- Me importa un ... < Palabrota que te venga a la mente >
- [Hakuna Matata](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-7MNFpAsqI) (Se tomó de la película animada 'Rey León', en mi país se usa mucho)
- Ni atrás ni adelante
- Ni fue ni será

P.D: A medida que vaya recordando voy agregando.

En cada país se puede encontrar una interpretación diferente. Yo soy de Cuba, pasé 2 años en Colombia, actualmente en Miami, USA.

---

Ahora estaba viendo vídeos y encontré este de Tego Calderon(Puerto Rico).

[NI FU NIFA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8X-tg4mmGQ)

Se usa en el lenguaje chabacano para expresar `ni una cosa ni la otra`.

Puedes leer los comentarios para ver la interpretación de la gente de muchos países.

Answer (score 2):

El sentido en el que más uso (y he escuchado en Colombia) «ni fu ni fa» es para expresar algo que se prometió y no se hizo por indecisión.  La mayoría de los sinónimos que veo expresan algo mediano o regular: *comme ci comme ça* (esta expresión francesa puede incluirse en la lista, la he escuchado en español, a veces escrita como «comsí comsá»).

Adicional a la respuesta de Emilio (que en gran parte extiende su interpretación), agrego aquí algunas respuestas con mi significado (algo no hecho por indecisión)

1. «ni chicha ni limonada» (usualmente «ni chicha ni limoná»)
2. «mucho tilín tilín y nada de paletas»
3. «con los crespos hechos»

<sup>Iré agregando si recuerdo otros.</sup>

Comment: Te digo lo mismo que a JavaRiser. Deberías indicar el país para el que aplica lo que dices, porque al menos en España no tiene el significado que explicas, sino el que indica la pregunta original. "Ni fu ni fa" indica que no te importa, válido por ejemplo como respuesta a "¿Tienes calor?"

Comment: @SysDragon, por otro lado Emilio tampoco indica su procedencia geográfica mientras indica que el término no se usa (salvo por personas mayores).  ¿Dónde no se usa? ¿Debe asumirse que si no se indica la procedencia geográfica ésta es España? ¿Si donde no se usa significa una cosa y donde sí se usa significa otra debe votarse negativamente el uso real?

Comment: Emilio continúa con el uso del significado proporcionado por la pregunta original, añadiendo la información que se pide. Si indicas una corrección de significado qué menos que indicar donde aplica, pues no es el significado que busca la pregunta original.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar **Ni lo uno ni lo otro**.

Ejemplos:

> P: Qué te parece la tesis?
>   R: Mmmm....ni fu ni fa. (me dá lo mismo, no me interesa)
>
> P: Cómo estás?
>   R: Ni fu ni fa (más o menos, ni bien ni mal).

Answer (score 2):

Esto realmente depende del país.

Por ejemplo acá en Chile, *ni fu ni fa* implica a expresar algo que no es ni una cosa ni la otra, entonces sinónimos de esta expresión pueden ser:

- no corta ni pincha.
- ni chicha ni limonada.

Depende bastante del contexto en donde se aplican estos dichos.

Answer (score 1):

Todas las de tu libro, en mi opinión, están mal:

1. así así
2. regular
3. sin pena ni gloria
4. medianamente
5. así no más
6. tal cual (tal por cual)
7. de por ahí
8. de tres al cuatro
9. como el tiempo malo
10. que llueve o no llueve
11. de tamaño regular

Todas esas son frases, pero ninguna tiene el mismo significado de "ni fu ni fa".  Ni fu ni fa quiere decir que no se hizo nada, o no pasó nada.  Quién sabe de donde venga esa frase tan rara, o por qué se hizo popular; pero si buscas otras frases con el mismo significado, yo recomiendo "ni peras ni manzanas".

Lo que yo diría es: "**pero no pasó nada, y ahí acabó**".

Comment: Deberías indicar el país para el que aplica lo que dices, porque al menos en España no tiene el significado que explicas, sino el que indica la pregunta original. "Ni fu ni fa" indica que no te importa, válido por ejemplo como respuesta a "¿Tienes calor?"

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this summary following what was discussed in [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/5481). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

---

### Chile

- No corta ni pincha.
- Ni chicha ni limonada.

### Colombia

- Ni chicha ni limonada (usualmente «ni chicha ni limoná»)
- Mucho tilín tilín y nada de paletas
- No raja ni presta el hacha
  <sub>Aunque sinónimos de "ni fu ni fa" estas frases se usan en situaciones diferentes y su interpretación depende del contexto</sub>

### Venezuela

- Ni frio ni calor
- Me da igual

Comment: En Venezuela "ni fu ni fa" se usa para significar que algo que sucede no me importa, "me da igual" "ni frio ni calor" "mas o menos"

Answer (score 1):

En México, *no fu ni fa* siempre connota indiferencia o desinterés. Expresa que no se está ni de acuerdo ni en desacuerdo con las opciones disponibles pero tampoco interesa mucho el asunto. Vamos, que el tema no te quita el sueño.

En toda ocasión, sería sinónimo de:

- Meh... (mejor si va acompañado de encogimiento de hombros)
- Ni me viene ni me va
- Me es igual
- Me resulta indiferente

Pero también, según la ocasión, podría ser reemplazado por otras frases.

En respuesta a "¿cómo estás?", "¿cómo salió el examen?" y similares:

- No me quejo
- Ahí vamos / Ahí fue
- Ahí dos tres

En respuesta a "¿Qué opinas de esto?":

- Me importa un comino (despectivo)
- Me vale (despectivo)