# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "ni fu ni fa"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

En España se usa con frecuencia la expresión "ni fu ni fa" para indicar indiferencia cuando algo no provoca mayor emoción.

> - ¿Qué te pareció esa película?
> - Ni fu ni fa [He visto mejores pero tampoco es mala]

He estado buscando un rato pero no acabo de encontrar explicación sobre el origen de la expresión, pues ni "fu" ni "fa" tienen mayor significado.

¿Alguien conoce alguno? ¿Se usa también en otras zonas?

Comment: Sí. Acá en Chile se usa como pan de cada día.

Comment: Estoy escuchando una canción de Charlie Boisseau - J'en ai des tas y una parte de la canción dice en Francés: Ça ne te fait ni chaud ni froid, es decir como "Eso no te hace ni calor ni frío", creo que tiene el mismo significado. Podría traducirse tranquilamente como "Eso no te hace ni fú ni fá".

Comment: Podría ser del italiano: > *né fu, né fa* = neither he/she/it was nor does/makes/acts = ni fue, ni hace/ actùa.

Comment: sera por que cunado dices "fu" el aire sale frio y cuando dices "fa" el aire sale caliente ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo tampoco he podido encontrar mucho. Hay quien dice que es de "origen incierto" y lo deja ahí (perdido para siempre). Por ejemplo en esta entrada de "De pé a pá / Ni fú ni fá "

> Hay dudas sobre su origen y aunque algunos han intentado dar explicaciones inverosímiles sustentando sus raíces en el vasco o en el hebreo, parece tratarse simplemente de una locución creada por el simple placer de la similitud o el sonsonete [...]
>
> Lo mismo es aplicable a la frase "ni fu ni fa", cuya creación debe ser más reciente y cuyo significado tanto puede ser "ni una cosa ni la otra", como "nada de nada", si bien pudiera interpretarse como analogía de otras locuciones, tales como "Ni chicha ni limoná" o "Ni carne ni pescado
>
> Fuente [Taringa: El origen de frases que siempre usamos](http://www.taringa.net/posts/info/1636864/El-origen-de-frases-que-siempre-usamos.html)

Y como dicen en este hilo del [Instituto Cervantes](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=34429), parece ser que es una simple locución usada por su valor expresivo.

> Pero, como lo último que quiero es aburrir al personal, diré sólo que se trata de un truco. Un truco para captar la atención; **para que la frase gane en sonoridad**. Las frases `¿María? Ni me gusta ni me deja de gustar` y `¿María? Ni fu ni fa` transmiten exactamente el mismo mensaje. La única diferencia consiste en que la segunda lo hace con mucha más expresividad.
>
> Fuente: Post 133691. del mencionado [CVC](http://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=34429)

Con lo que estas entradas nos vienen a decir que no tiene un origen "lógico", sino que es más "casualidad" o "sonoridad". De la misma manera que uno puede decir que `Me sé la lección de la A a la Z`, que tiene su lógica porque A y Z son la primera y última letras del alfabeto, una de las primeras y más básicas cosas que aprendemos en el colegio, también puede decir `Me sé la lección **de pe a pa**`, que no tiene mucha lógica (Como si dijésemos, "me lo sé de ka a ki/ de tu a ti"), pero es más "sonoro" y más expresivo.

Este documento, [«Neologismos fraseológicos» como palabras diacríticas
en las locuciones en español](http://www.paremia.org/wp-content/uploads/05-AGUILAR.pdf)  explica

> los procesos de configuración de tus ni mus y de ni fu ni fa, si proceden del
>   sonido interjectivo para llamar o espantar al perro (tus, en DRAE, DCECH) o de la consciente imitación onomatopéyica del bufido del gato (fu, en DPL) y una adición silábica (mus, con la consiguiente colisión homonímica con un referente existente en el sistema) o reduplicación de naturaleza apofónica (fa).

Con lo que le atribuye también un origen "fonético - onomatopéyico", no muy distinto a otras expresiones (como *de pe a pa* o *asín o asá*)

Comment: Pues "por hache o por be" que me gusta la respuesta :D

Answer (score 2):

Una vez oí en "La Tremenda Corte" que "fu" se refiere a "fulastre" (=malo) y "fa" a "fabuloso", es decir, algo ni bueno ni malo.

Comment: Interesante, ¿podrías obtener más información sobre el capítulo donde se explicó esto? Para tener referencias concretas. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Estoy buscando un posible origen de la expresión, pero no encuentro nada concluyente. En el NTLLE el primer diccionario que recoge la expresión es el *Diccionario enciclopédico de la lengua castellana* compuesto por Elías Zerolo en 1895:

> *Ni fu ni fa*. fr. fam. Se dice de aquellas cosas que pudiéramos llamar indiferentes ó neutras. Así, por ejemplo, empleamos esta frase hablando de manjares insípidos, de personas que no son buenas ni malas, etc.

Y el primer texto que la usa lo encuentro en la hemeroteca de la BNE, en un ejemplar que, hablando de una corrida de toros, decía:

> *Currito ni fú ni fá.*
>
> Boletín de loterías y de toros (Madrid). 10/5/1875, n.º 1.263, página 4.

Lo que no es cierto es que "fu" no "fa" no signifiquen nada por sí solos. Desde 1787 se recoge en diccionarios la expresión "fu" como "voz antigua de desprecio" o "interjección de quien está enojado". Por tanto, decir que algo no es "ni fu ni fa" puede ser "algo que no desprecias, pero tampoco lo contrario".